# Image flow out of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve an image flowing out of a div. Basically, in my heading I have a fixed width of 960px, the logo image has something coming off of it, which I would like to sit outside that 960px.

Is there a nice clean method of achieving this?

Comment: Do you have some example of what you have so far?

Comment: In Bootstrap, img-fluid class makes an image fit to the size of div.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simple method of doing it (that works in most browsers), is that you make your main wrapper have `position:relative`, and the make the div (that you want to flow outside) have `position: absolute; left: -25px; top: -25px;`.

Having `position:relative` as the wrapper makes the `position:absolute` relative inside the parent container.

Comment: Great, seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

put your logo in fixed div and give that div a style `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 2):

You could also absolute positioning to achieve this. Quick example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/9QJ4w/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `position` property of CSS to accomplish this:

HTML:

```
<div><p>Some content<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></p></div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 175px;
}

div p
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 175px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

div img
{
    position: relative;
    right: 140px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FpTDc/

Answer (score 0):

Your friend will be overflow:visible.

Your containing div will have the 960px width with overflow:visible.  Inside, you will have a relatively or absolutely positioned image  (you will need to offset 'left' to center it)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <img src="" />
</div>

div { width:300px; height:100px; background:red; margin:100px; }
img { width:100px; height:100px; background:green; margin:-20px 0 0 -20px; }
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/cSQrR/

Answer (score 0):

it's due to the images having different sizes and aspect ratios.

try this:

```css
 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```