# How do move content outside of the main content area?

Tags: html, css, sass

[screenshot of the problematic part of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B72MO.png)
I layout a training layout from figma. Most of the content is inside the 1160px wide content area, but some of the photo and circle content is outside of that content area. What is the best way to move the photo and circle outside the content area?

```
 <div class="big__title">
            <div class="header__other">
                <h1>robo school</h1>
                <p>Курсы повышения квалификации по робототехнике для педагогов начальной школы</p>
                <a href="" class="sign__btn">Записаться на курс</a>
            </div>
            <div class="woman">
                <img src="https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com/img/75b1/c000/25b83366e2fa5d28f23b6174a9411adb?Expires=1698624000&Signature=YR02fL1dMyRubJQJK00FqUeNd2nKF5kZBNT60hfMCeoVm-g8IvepPEqn4PlEcmvVuGyzg04DnNr5i-t~W~Pt32~W2EnsGFWxPRXJ1BXR6ekuqeNu3qNHyxt3JKk7Tkfo5btrn7DRZAGb-Zh4B5hDulL0y68DIhv1o--jmQ46OGfriWftoZ63dTRL63M~~3Y49lr~AiOBApUaV5bkB~he9DsdHn-7IybDO5hvzpP2SzPv91Uo3WNcjZnJfuI8KH-4yNQj8knqyhfiUAthAbbLkAI-8VWrvb7vJroGBMuM0DuPHhYU-9xbGmajwOJz-gPJjmZkPQDg-POI9EIolpo0eg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAQ4GOSFWCVNEHN3O4"
                    alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.big__title {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1160px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    h1 {
        color: #FFF;
            font-size: 70px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 160%;
            /* 112px */
    }
    p {
        color: #FFF;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 160%;
            /* 32px */
    }
    a {
        color:#FFF;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 160%;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: #D52027;
            padding: 25px 54px;
    }
}
.woman {
    img{
    width: 515px;
    }
}
.header__other
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

P.S. I apologize in advance for my English, translated by "DeepL"

The only thing I could think of doing was to give a negative "margin-right" value, for the block with the picture, but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image flow out of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339415/image-flow-out-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

A negative right margin on the image is the solution I would use. I’m guessing that perhaps an error in the arrangement of your CSS prevented it from taking effect? Remember that CSS nesting is still not fully supported.

```css
body {
  background: navy;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.big__title {
  width: 1160px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
  border: 1px solid white;
}  

.big__title h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.big__title p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 160%;
}

.big__title a {
  color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 160%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #D52027;
  padding: 25px 54px;
}

.woman img {
  width: 215px;
  margin-right: -50px;
}

.header__other h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="big__title">
  <div class="header__other">
    <h1>robo school</h1>
    <p>Курсы повышения квалификации по робототехнике для педагогов начальной школы</p>
    <a href="" class="sign__btn">Записаться на курс</a>
  </div>
  <div class="woman">
    <img src="https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com/img/75b1/c000/25b83366e2fa5d28f23b6174a9411adb?Expires=1698624000&Signature=YR02fL1dMyRubJQJK00FqUeNd2nKF5kZBNT60hfMCeoVm-g8IvepPEqn4PlEcmvVuGyzg04DnNr5i-t~W~Pt32~W2EnsGFWxPRXJ1BXR6ekuqeNu3qNHyxt3JKk7Tkfo5btrn7DRZAGb-Zh4B5hDulL0y68DIhv1o--jmQ46OGfriWftoZ63dTRL63M~~3Y49lr~AiOBApUaV5bkB~he9DsdHn-7IybDO5hvzpP2SzPv91Uo3WNcjZnJfuI8KH-4yNQj8knqyhfiUAthAbbLkAI-8VWrvb7vJroGBMuM0DuPHhYU-9xbGmajwOJz-gPJjmZkPQDg-POI9EIolpo0eg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAQ4GOSFWCVNEHN3O4" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```